# How to clean up a question whose answer is built up across several comments?

Tags: discussion

I'm asking because of a current question I'm working on. [How to print formatted text from a web server with confirmation of successful printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848921/how-to-print-formatted-text-from-a-web-server-with-confirmation-of-successful-pr)

I had started a bounty, and the one answer doesn't answer the question completely. Though I'm working on it and the other user and myself have been trying to work through it in the comments.  Assuming it does get solved, how would I best consolidate the comments into the answer, so that the answer is correct but all the information that got us there is still accessible?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the link, totally a mis-paste.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We're a Question and Answer site, not a Forum. It's traditional in a forum that you have to dig through endless comments, not knowing if there's an anwer in there.

**Stack Exchange Does Not Work That Way**.

If the answer is in a comment, suggest someone make that an answer. If they don't, feel free to make the answer yourself if you have reason to believe the original "answerer" isn't going to.

If it's your question that doesn't have an answer and you found the solution, **answer your own question** and leave all info someone else would need to solve your problem. It doesn't matter that the answer was found through comments; long term, your question should have an answer, an accepted answer, when your problem is solved. Short term it might seem rude to take someone else's answer, but not doing so is even ruder to the hundreds or thousands of people that might find your question.

Answer (score 3):

Where possible answers should not be left embedded within comments. Comment chains can get quite lengthy, and a future reader shouldn't have to dig through that to distill the answer.

When the answer has been assembled by several authors in the comment section then a good option is to aggregate those comments into an answer, but mark it as Community Wiki. An example of this can be found right here in [this answer](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/a/763/70) to the question [How important is lineage when it comes to credibility or trustworthiness?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/759/how-important-is-lineage-when-it-comes-to-credibility-or-trustworthiness) on the MartialArts.SE site. Of course this doesn't preclude others also leaving answers.